# Как в composer очистить список загруженных классов а затем вызвать с новыми сидерами?

Tags: php, composer, laravel5, artisan

Как очистить список загруженных классов после команды `composer dump-autoload`?

Мне необходимо сымитировать ошибку:

> ReflectionException  : Class AddNewSeeder does not exist

После команды:

`php artisan db:seed --class="AddNewSeeder"`

> **UPD** Даже после выполнения следующих команд в скрипте (`DatabaseSeeder.php`) `seeder` не виден для `Artisan`

```
exec('cd vendor/composer && rm autoload_*');
exec('composer dump-autoload -o');
$this->call(Myseeder::class);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32725785/can-i-undo-composers-dump-autoload

Comment: @Let'ssayPie обновил вопрос.

Comment: `seeder не виден для Artisan` как вы об этом узнали?

Comment: @РустамГимранов `ReflectionException : Class AddNewSeeder does not exist`. А в файлах `autoload_classmap.php` и `autoload_static.php` запись появилась.

Comment: Вам нужно `с имитировать` или победить ошибку?

Comment: @РустамГимранов я уже с имитировал. Теперь не могу победить)

Comment: Composer обновите, и посмотрите как на гитхабе в Laravel в файле composer.json прописаны пути к заполнителям.

Comment: @РустамГимранов `composer` обновлён. И при чём тут `composer.json`?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101366/discussion-between-doox911-and--).

Answer (score 0):

UPD: **вариант не рабочий**

Немного покопавшись в исходниках `Laravel` я выяснил на каком этапе он не понимает где найти класс и нашёл метод, через который легально можно указать фреймворку путь к вашему классу.

Объект `Seeder` содержит внутри себя свойство-объект `container` с типом `Illuminate\Container`.
В этом объекте хранится информация о загруженных классах, в массиве `instances`.

С помощью метод [instance](https://github.com/illuminate/container/blob/master/Container.php#L407) можно добавить необходимый класс в массив `instances`, для этого нужно передать **полный путь** к необходимому классу и его экземпляр.

Соответственно после этого при вызове метода `call` у вашего *сида* в этой [части кода](https://github.com/illuminate/container/blob/master/Container.php#L669) будет найден необходимый класс.

Ваш код должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
$this->container->instance('AddNewSeeder', new Database\Seeds\AddNewSeeder());
$this->call('AddNewSeeder');
```

Comment: К сожалению, ваш вариант не рабочий.

Comment: да, проверил - не работает

Answer (score -1):

Решил проблему иначе. Написал скрипт (`bash`):

```
#!/bin/bash

clear;
echo "Start script..\n\n";
composer dump-autoload -o;
php artisan migrate;
php artisan db:seed;
echo "Done!"
```